# Home wifi connection is very inconsistent and also my 5G as well. What is going on?

Tags: wi-fi

My phone tends to lose connection to the internet when I'm connected to my home wifi. Throughout the day, I will be watching youtube videos only to run into buffering as I lose connection. Then maybe a couple minutes later, it returns, or sometimes I manually disconnect my connection to my wifi and reconnect to fix the issue immediately.

I don't understand why it is doing this. I know the wifi itself isn't losing connection to the internet because my Xbox and PC are both connected to the same wifi and I haven't experienced lost of connection at all when I'm browsing the internet on my PC or playing online games on my Xbox.

Another thing is, my 5g connection isn't working as I would like it either at my home. At work, I don't even connect to the company wifi at all. I use my 5G mobile data to all day as I have unlimited data and it works perfectly at work as well as whenever I'm out and about. I'll watch Netflix, Youtube, etc and won't experience any lost of connection.

But when I'm home, I wouldn't be as mad about experiencing these wifi issues if my 5G unlimited mobile data also worked but it doesn't work as well neither. Usually I'll be using wifi, lose connection when my youtube video stops, turn off the wifi to switch over to 5G, still don't get connection to internet so I manually reconnect to my wifi and I get internet again, or I do get internet with my 5G only to lose connection maybe a couple minutes later.

Is there some signal interfering with my phone to both the wifi and the 5G network? I have two Xboxes both connected wirelessly to the wifi and they both work flawlessly. The smart TV as well.

---

I have the Galaxy S21 Ultra by the way but the previous phone I had, my Galaxy S9+ also experienced these same spotty internet connections as well at home.

---

**UPDATE**

---

**Some Info on my WIFI**

---

**SpeedTest**

- Provider = ATT U-verse
- 5GHz Wifi Signal Strength = -50dBm
- Router Model = BGW210
- Ping = 57ms
- Download = 30.27 Mbps
- Upload = 12.08 Mbps

---

**Wifi-Client Connection Statistics of Some Devices**

---

MAC Address: (Galaxy S21 Ultra) |  Authentication State: Connected | IP Address: xx | Access Point: 5GHzxx | Transmit Packets: 100203 | Receive Packets: 41983 | Transmit Bytes: 106343914 | Receive Bytes: 7400949 | Trans Errors: 0 | Signal Strength: -69dBm | Disassoc Count: 1197 | Death Count: 2

---

MAC Address: (Galaxy S9+) |  Authentication State: Connected | IP Address: xx | Access Point: 5GHzxx | Transmit Packets: 282677 | Receive Packets: 93193 | Transmit Bytes: 386678945 | Receive Bytes: 14062960 | Trans Errors: 0 | Signal Strength: -61dBm | Disassoc Count: 1 | Death Count: 0

---

MAC Address: (Xbox1X) |  Authentication State: Connected | IP Address: xx | Access Point: 5GHzxx | Transmit Packets: 149483 | Receive Packets: 70467 | Transmit Bytes: 203467990 | Receive Bytes: 10668784 | Trans Errors: 0 | Signal Strength: -62dBm | Disassoc Count: 10 | Death Count: 4

Comment: Where do you live and which Wifi channels (2.4/5GHz) do you use Wifi? How many other Wifis are around you?

Comment: I live in South Florida near Miami. There's a 2.4 GHz and 5GHz connection to my wifi meaning each have their own SSIDs and passwords but both are inconsistent in terms of connection with my phone with the 2.4GHz probably being more inconsistent. My tv, pc, and xbox all use the 5GHz connection. This is an ATT Home Wifi system by the way. There are 5 Wifi connections showing in my area inluding my wifi.

Comment: Also, i'm looking at my wifi signal right now on my phone and its giving me one bar?? I'm literally the next room over where our wifi router is and I just walked in that room and it is still one bar. When I switch to my 5G, my bar is still one bar as well.